# Solve for $x$ in $x^{2x+1}=x^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^{2x+1}=x^4$

I tried:

$$x^{2x+1}=x^4 \Leftrightarrow -x^4 + (x^x)^2 \cdot x = 0 \Leftrightarrow ???$$

I have no idea of what to do next.

How to I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$x^{2x+1}=x^4$

Case 1:
$x=0$

Case 2:
$x\neq0$, so we can divide:
$x^{2x-3}=1$

So either $x=1$
$x=-1$ (<-this need to be checked, the exponent has to be even)
or $2x-3=0$ (<-this also need to be checked, the base has to be non-zero)
Turns out $x=-1$ is not a solution.

Answer: $x=0,1,\frac 32$

Comment: How did you know this equation had exactly 3 solutions?Do you have any method for knowing what possible cases there are?

Comment: This is the so-called prove by cases. First I split the cases into zero and non-zero $x$. For the non-zero $x$, I split again: zero and non-zero exponents.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^{ 2x+1 }=x^{ 4 }\quad \Rightarrow 2x+1=4\Rightarrow \quad x=\frac { 3 }{ 2 } $$
note that $x=0$ and $x=1$ are trivial solutions

Comment: $x=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: @u1571372,good point thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ 2x + 1 = 4 \implies x = 3/2 $$